# NgbDropdown: remove dropdown arrow

Tags: css, angular, ng-bootstrap, angular2-ui-bootstrap

I'm using the `NgbDropdown` component in my Angular 2 application. It is working fine, however I want to remove the arrow that is displayed on the right side of the button.

```
<div class="d-inline-block" ngbDropdown #myDrop="ngbDropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-outline-primary" id="dropdownMenu1" ngbDropdownToggle>Toggle dropdown</button>
  <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
    <button class="dropdown-item">Action - 1</button>
    <button class="dropdown-item">Another Action</button>
    <button class="dropdown-item">Something else is here</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

[Dropdown Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7qfof.png)

Answer (score 75, accepted):

### Solution

Simply add the following CSS style to override the default style of the `.dropdown-toggle::after` pseudo-element:

```
.dropdown-toggle::after {
    display:none;
}
```

### Why?

By default bootstrap adds the arrow to the dropdown component via the [`::after`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::after) [pseudo-element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-elements).

Doing this removes it.

Here is a **[LIVE DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/AZFXCr7YjCZz4g5oUj8E?p)** demonstrating it.

### How do you work it out?

Using chrome dev tools you can inspect the element:

[image]

We can see from the above that there is a style set for a pseudo-element ::after on the `.dropdown-toggle` class. Let's go and change the properties of the element! For this purpose we are changing the `display` property to `none`:

[image]

The pseudo-element is no longer there!!:

[image]

Comment: I have to add this class too which was still visible on bottom elements of the screen:

.dropup .dropdown-toggle::after {
    display:none;
}

Comment: @cnorthfield:sir can you how to add above css via condtionally in my case i have to hide above only if ccondtion true?

Answer (score 8):

add the following style to override the default one

```
.dropdown-toggle::after{
    content:initial
 }
```

**[LIVE DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/S2SZJsAIVSXvCiSvjCn4?p=preview)**

Answer (score 3):

In Bootstrap 4, you can remove the dropdown arrow which is called caret by declaring a `$enable-caret` SASS variable and setting it to `false`:

```
$enable-caret: false;
```

This overrides the default value of `true` set in the Bootstrap's `_variable.scss`:

```
// Options
//
// Quickly modify global styling by enabling or disabling optional features.

$enable-caret:                                true !default;
```

But keep in mind that it completely removes corresponding CSS styles. So, it's the best approach if you don't need carets globally and want to decrease your CSS payload.

Answer (score 2):

I found you can do this within your app on a conditional basis by creating a custom class in styles.css

Note that using "!important;" is required or else elements at the bottom of the screen will still have a caret that points upward:

```
.remove-caret::after {
    display: none !important;
}
```

html example with the custom class and replacing the icon with an ellipsis:

```
<div style="margin: auto; text-align: center">
                        <ul class="navbar-nav" [style.display]="'flex'">
                            <li class="nav-item d-inline-block" ngbDropdown>
                                <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle remove-caret" style="color:#000; font-size: 1.1rem" ngbDropdownToggle href="#" role="button" aria-haspopup="true"
                                   aria-expanded="false"><fa-icon [icon]="faEllipsisH" class="ml-2"></fa-icon></a>
                                <div ngbDropdownMenu aria-labelled-by="menuDropDown">
                                    <a ngbDropdownItem href="#" (click)="test()">Test</a>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
```